# NGINX - Proxy (I think)

Tags: nginx

so I have 4 instances of node running for 4 different sites. I want to use Nginx, here is what I want.

```
www.site1.co.uk
= localhost:50010

www.site2.co.uk
= localhost:50020

www.site3.co.uk
= localhost:50030

test.site3.co.uk
=localhost:50031
```

I'm not asking for the code, (although it would be nice), what is the best way to achieve this sort of setup? I am still new to Nginx so sorry if it's a really simple question.

Thanks in advance,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

To proxy the requests to those ports according to the domain being requested use this

```
server {
    server_name www.site1.co.uk
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50010
}
server {
    server_name www.site2.co.uk
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50020
}
server {
    server_name www.site3.co.uk
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50030
}
server {
    server_name test.site1.co.uk
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50031
}
```